# Ошибка в запросе к БД "Column 'day_reports_id' cannot be null" - хотя это внешний ключ

Tags: laravel, laravel5, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel5.4

Получаю ошибку:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'day_reports_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `elementary_reports` (`type`, `project`, `subproject`, `report`, `time`, `day_reports_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Рабочее время, Рабочее время, Рабочее время, Рабочее время, 5, , 2018-08-20 21:04:51, 2018-08-20 21:04:51))
```

Суть ее ясна, но почему-то автоматически не подставляется нужный id из связанной таблицы..

Миграции (для **id** установлен **increments**, а также используется ключ **foreign** и **references**):

```
Schema::create('day_reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('username');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('elementary_reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('day_reports_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('day_reports_id')->references('id')->on('day_reports');
        $table->text('type');
        $table->text('project');
        $table->text('subproject')->nullable();
        $table->text('report');
        $table->double('time');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Контроллер (сделал как в документации):

```
  $dayReport = new DayReport();
    $dayReport -> username = Auth::user()->name;

    $dayReport->elementaryReports()->saveMany([
        new ElementaryReport(['type' => 'Рабочее время', 'project' => 'Рабочее время', 'subproject' => 'Рабочее время', 'report' => 'Рабочее время', 'time' => 5]),
        new ElementaryReport(['type' => 'Рабочее врем2', 'project' => 'Рабочее врем2', 'subproject' => 'Рабочее врем2', 'report' => 'Рабочее врем2', 'time' => 6]),
    ]);
```

Модель (указал привязку между двумя таблицами через внешний ключ **day_reports_id**):

```
class DayReport extends Model{
public function elementaryReports()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ElementaryReport', 'day_reports_id', 'id');
}
```

Что здесь может быть не так?

Answer (score 0):

У вас в коде вы написали

```
$dayReport = new DayReport();
```

Это просто экземпляр объекта, **он не вставлен в бд!**

Это значить что `$dayReport` не имеет id. А как будет работать `saveMany` которому надои `id` для `day_reports_id`?

Попробуйте так:

```
$dayReport = DayReport::create([
    'username' => auth()->user()->name
]);
```